# Making shell_exec work the way sh does with omxplayer

Tags: raspbian, video, php

I have apache2, php5 installed. I'm trying to execute the next code in my php script

```
chdir('/var/www/');
shell_exec('/usr/bin/omxplayer -o hdmi "'.$file_name.'" < omfifo &');
shell_exec('echo -n . > omfifo');
```

`$file_name` is a file and it does exist in `/var/www` directory. `www-data` user is in sudoers file. `/var/www/` is `0777`. generally `shell_exec` does work I checked it with this code

```
<?php
shell_exec('sh boo.sh');
?>
```

boo.sh

```
echo "Download finished" | wall;
```

When I execute the code with omxplayer in just a console it works fine.
I can also launch omxplayer from php without using pipes, but I do need them.

Comment: have you solves this? i have the same problem..

Answer (score 2):

OK, I had the same problems, so here were the things which helped me:

1. Go to `/etc/apache2`, and in the file `envvars`, change `login`, and `user` group to `pi`, or the user you are using. (P.S. This thing is really bad for website security, if you plan to publish the website, you will need to play around with user groups!). By doing that you are changing the user `apache` uses to execute code.
2. Change every function to it's full name (`ls` --> `/bin/ls`, using sudo: `/usr/bin/sudo`, you can find this information by writing in the terminal `whereis sudo`)
3. Use `\` in front of special characters in Php, so:

   ```
   echo('Hello - **'Max'** ');
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   echo('Hello **\'Max\'** ');
   ```
4. Check your `apache` error log. It is located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. In that file there is every error Php has encountered.

So, I hope that does it. If it did not, I suggest removing variables in your code, and trying to pinpoint the bug. By the way, `omxplayer` can take a long time to load, so be sure to wait 1-2 minutes before quitting.